# Convert shapfile(.shp) to SQL server 2008 using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geometry, gis, shapefile

Is there any library in .Net to convert shapefile to SQL server table? I need it programatically from the c#.Net.

Can anybody know? Please help me on this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL.aspx

Comment: I wonder if there's a C# API for GDAL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not going to be that straightforward since you need to also read the records and features in the file that may or may not exist. (DBF File)

If you need a free library to read the data - look at http://shapefile.codeplex.com/